# TEI and XSLT: No content in output file

Tags: xml, xslt

I have a xml document structured in the TEI "standard", maybe some of you know it. 
I made a XSLT to transform this into another XML structure.

But I came to a problem. The transformation process doesn't reach a specific node in the XML structure.

The original document looks like following:

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:tgl="http://******/namespaces  /metadata/language/2010" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:tns="http://*****/namespaces/metadata/core/2010" xmlns:tgr="http://*****/namespaces/metadata/agent/2010" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:tgs="http://*****/namespaces/metadata/script/2010" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xml:id="tg397" n="/Literatur/M/Birlinger, Anton/Märchen und Sagen/Sagen, Märchen, Volksaberglauben/3./299. Von den Sternen/2. [Die Sterne halten Viele für die Köpfe silberner Nägel]">
<teiHeader xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" xmlns:a="http://www.*****/namespace/digibib/authors" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">

<fileDesc>
    <titleStmt>
    <title> hshshhshs </title>
</titleStmt>
<publicationStmt>
   ....
```

With my XSLT I try to reach some nodes. Because it doesn't I try a simple example, but I can't reach the content of  .
This is XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>
    <!--<xsl:template match="/TEI">-->
 <xsl:template match="/">


        <add><doc>
            <field name="title">
                <xsl:value-of select="TEI/teiHeader/fileDesc/titleStmt/title"/>
            </field>-
        </doc></add>


 </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

And this is the result:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <add>
   <doc>
    <field name="title"/>-

       </doc>
   </add>
```

I hope that somebody of you can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the TEI document starts off with this line

```
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
```

This means all the elements within the document, unless otherwise specfied with a namespace prefix, are in the namespace ""http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"

However, in your XSLT document you are trying to select elements with no namespace, and so it doesn't match the ones in the TEI which do have a namespace.

The solution is to first declare the relevant namespace in your XSLT document, using any prefix you like:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
   xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
   xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0"
   version="1.0">
```

Then you can write your XLST statement like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="tei:TEI/tei:teiHeader/tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title"/>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I was struggling with myself yesterday. This seems so logical but I didn't come to my mind. 

Thumbs up!